# How should I fix my x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my graph when I graph the month and year of houses sold by the prices of the houses. I was wondering as to how I could make x-axis look nicer without loosing too much information in the graph.

Here is my code:

```
month_year_of_date <- paste(month_of_date, year_of_date, sep = "/")

ggplot(housing_data, aes(x = factor(month_year_of_date), y = housing_data$price)) + 
    geom_point()

plot(factor(test), housing_data$price)
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to see some example `housing_data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the labels by 45 degrees as below:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: @Andy If the answer addresses your problem, you can mark it correct with the check mark on the left.